# Formatting data frame to allow for dodged bar plotting

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Good afternoon,

I have just asked a very similar question but I think I may have misworded it as the question was closed and I was pointed towards an answer which did not help me (it was showing me how to plot, not how to format the data before plotting).

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(cluster = c(1, 2), age = c(0.67, 0.39), resting_bps = c(0.42, 
0.29), cholesterol = c(0.3, 0.26), max_bps = c(0.51, 0.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

And I would like to be able to format this data so that I can plot a dodged bar plot with the different biomedical values (resting BPS, cholesterol, etc.) for the two different clusters next to one another, like the plot I have included below.

[image]

How can I manipulate this data frame so that I can use an iteration of the following code to create the above plot for my specific data frame?

Example of code to use:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= blank, y=blank, fill = blank)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")
```

***Please do not close this question early by pointing me towards the code showing me how to plot a dodged bar plot. The point of my question is to ask experienced R programmers how I can manipulate the data frame so that the '*ggplot()*' function works with my data.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. The key in `ggplot2` is always reshaping data to long. You can do that using `tidyverse` functions and then sketch the plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(1:2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=factor(cluster)))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-pivot_longer(df,-1)
ggplot(df, aes(x= name, y=value, fill = as.character(cluster))) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
 scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")
```

[image]